# file size in c program

Tags: c

I just want to find the file size with the help of c program..I wrote a code but it give wrong result...

```
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
osize=ftell(fp);
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean "wrong result"?  What did you get, what were you expecting, and why did you expect it?  Also, how did you open the file?

Comment: Did you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: @David: I think it's a text mode/binary mode issue.

Comment: Its give me a negative file size....

Comment: ya i opened it in binary mode.

Comment: is there any chance osize is an int and not long?

Comment: @Sujoy::Can you right-click your file and see the size in properties? What is the size there?

Comment: Okay, now tell us how `osize` is declared, what the negative value was, and about how big the file really is.  There is a possibility that the value is too big for `osize`, but without information it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

The `stat` system call is the usual solution to this problem. Or, in your particular case, `fstat`.

Answer (score 2):

ftell returns an int.  If you are on a system where int is 32 bits and your file is more than 2GB, you may very well end up with a negative size. POSIX provides ftello and fseeko which use a off_t.  C has fgetpos and fsetpos which use a fpos_t -- but fpos_t is not an arithmetic type -- it keeps things related to the handling of charset by the locale for instance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why it should not work.

*Is there any other way?*
You can use stat, if you know the filename:

```
struct stat st;
stat(filename, &st);
size = st.st_size;
```

By the way [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ftell/) returns a `long int`

The [sys/stat.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html) header defines the structure of the data returned by the functions `fstat()`, `lstat()`, and `stat()`.

Comment: where is the definition of stat or what the body of stat contain?

Comment: @Sujoy:: See the edit. Btw you did not tell the size of your file by simply right-clicking on it and checking properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [_filelength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfbc2kec.aspx). It's not portable, though... I don't think there's any completely portable way to do this.

Comment: _filelength doesn't work with file pointers. However you can always do this: size = _filelength(_fileno(fp));

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `fstat()`:

```
int file=0;
if((file=open(<filename>,O_RDONLY)) < -1)
    return -1; // some error with open()

struct stat fileStat;
if(fstat(file,&fileStat) < 0)    
    return -1; // some error with fstat()

printf("File Size: %d bytes\n",fileStat.st_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only negative return value by `ftell` is -1L if an error occurs. If you don't mind using WinAPI, get file size with [`GetFileSizeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filename, 
                          GENERIC_READ,
                          0, 
                          NULL,
                          OPEN_EXISTING, 
                          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                          NULL);

LARGE_INTEGER size;
GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &size);
printf("%ld", size.QuadPart);

CloseHandle(hFile);
```