# How to get the size of a file

Tags: c++, c, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using C++ filestreams (fstream), how can you determine the size of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409504/using-c-filestreams-fstream-how-can-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file)
>   [file size in c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757353/file-size-in-c-program)

I want to retrive the size of a file and for this I implemented in this way

```
(void)fseek(m_fp, 0, SEEK_END); // Set the file pointer to the end of the file
pFileSize = ftell(m_fp);        // Get the file size
(void)fseek(m_fp, oldFilePos, SEEK_SET);  // Put back the file pointer at the original location
```

This is not feasible for out need and is ther anyother way to get the file size or check whether the file contain and data

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: why is it not feasible to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2409504/1025391

Comment: @moooeeeep Because it invokes undefined behavior? From the C standard: `A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END.`, `Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream...`

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze that is indeed nice to know. But the OP didn't specify that he's dealing with a binary stream.

Comment: @moooeeeep: For a text file, it's not the size of the file either.

Comment: If you're not afraid of the cutting edge, [`std::tr2::file_size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874829)

Comment: This is a duplicate, but not of 2409504.  This question is more about C than C++, so 5757353 is a more accurate duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

You can use stat

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#if defined (_WIN32)
#  include <io.h> // make portable for windows
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

struct stat st;
stat (filename, &st);
std::cout << st.st_size;
```

Comment: Note that stat is not a part of C or C++ but POSIX.

Comment: fstat() or fstat64() are variations on stat() that use a FILE *. Given you already have m_fp in your code, I suggest you use fstat().

Comment: [fstat ()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) uses int file handle (returned by `open`) and not `FILE*` (from `fopen`)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a binary stream, then pFileSize is the number of bytes from oldFilePos to the end of the file.

Comment: From the C standard: `A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END.`, `Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream...`

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is a 100% multiplatform way of doing what you need. Use your operating system's calls to do more, `stat()` on Unix-like OSes or `GetFileAttributesEx()` on Windows.

Comment: -1. No, it's not. From the C standard: `A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END.`, `Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream...`

Comment: Is there actually such a platform that doesn't support SEEK_END in stdio?

Comment: I can't tell your for sure what platforms (compilers/stdlibs/OSes) don't support it, but I think I have been beaten by it once.